# rtl8821ce driver issues on fedora 36 (5.19.11-200.fc36.x86_64)

Tags: fedora, wifi, drivers, realtek

recently I had errors with my wifi drivers (Realtek RTL8821CE) and I tried [this drivers](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce) but when i tried to install them this showed up:

```
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

[sudo] password for :
About to run dkms install steps...
./dkms-install.sh: line 15: dkms: command not found
./dkms-install.sh: line 16: dkms: command not found
./dkms-install.sh: line 17: dkms: command not found
Finished running dkms install steps.

and I also tried to uninstall them this showed up:

```
sudo ./dkms-remove.sh
[sudo] password for : 
About to run dkms removal steps...
./dkms-remove.sh: line 13: dkms: command not found
Finished running dkms removal steps.
```

Don't really know what to do right now and I'm in need of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dkms-install.sh` is a scrip that *makes use of* `dkms`, it does *not* install `dkms`.

As the error code tells you, `dkms` is not a known command.

So first make sure `dkms` is installed. For fedora e.g. via

```
sudo yum makecache --refresh
sudo yum -y install dkms
```

Once this is done, run the above script.

Comment: figured out it was another problem, thanks anyway